# Add a legend (like a matplotlib legend) to an image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

**Problem : Add a legend (like a matplotlib legend) to an image**

**Description:**

I have an image as a numpy array uint8.
I want to add a legend to it, exactly as matplotlib does with its plots.

My image has , basically, this shape :

```
output_image = np.empty(shape=(x,x, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
    # B-G-R-A
blue = [255, 0, 0, 255]
green = [0, 255, 0, 255]
red = [0, 0, 255, 255]
orange = [0, 128, 255, 255]
black = [0, 0, 0, 255]
    ...
```

The colors above are added.
Then the image is returned. And when it is returned by the method, i would like to add a graphic to it.

**Example Below. Instead of the graphic, i would have an image**

[image: Example]

**Extra Information**

The output is a numpy array with values ranging from 0 to 255.
Each pixel, value in the array, is formed by a 4-D array ( Blue-Green-Red-Alpha)

The legend should be added in the bottom right of the image.

The reason is because i have to do it, i guess.

Basically the current output is the numpy array, which i later use for other purposes.

Comment: Add more information. What kind of legend? Where? Why? What's the current output?

Comment: Done, please let me know if you need more information

Comment: How should these edits help? We still don't know anything about the desired content of the legend. And you are using imshow to print the image? I just try to imagine what kind of legend i would want to add if i would plot a colored-image of some face. (Line 1 ??? Probably not)

Comment: I want to add information about the image, like :"amount of pixels : 1000,"colors : bla bla bla" and so on. Im not using imshow or matplotlib to show the image or save it.

Comment: Then it's not a legend, but some textbox. Read the docs. For real help it's still way too broad (as so much stuff is unclear).

Comment: It is a legend as it shows information of the image.

Comment: Also, i gave as much information as you asked. If you dont want to help then dont.

Comment: You did not, but that's ok. Some people here eager to get help invest something, some do not. It's often not relevant what the semantic meaning of the word legend is, but what matplotlib thinks about it (naturally connected to plotted-stuff; different from a text-box).

Comment: Then tell me what else do you want to know. Because everything you asked i answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question itself makes it clear that you know how to make an image in a numpy array. Now make your legend using the same techniques in a smaller numpy array.

Finally, use the facilities in numpy to replace part of the plot array with the legend array, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506204/replace-sub-part-of-matrix-by-another-small-matrix-in-numpy)

Comment: Good Idea! Didnt think about this approach! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're very welcome. Didn't occur to me at first either.