# Python: using list to index [from:to] arbitrary numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to copy a chunk from a matrix into a piece of another matrix. 
To use this with any kind of n-dimensional array, I need to apply a list with offsets via the [] operator. Is there a way to do this?

```
mat_bigger[0:5, 0:5, ..] = mat_smaller[2:7, 2:7, ..]
```

like:

```
off_min = [0,0,0]
off_max = [2,2,2]
for i in range(len(off_min)):
  mat_bigger[off_min[i] : off_max[i], ..] = ..
```

Comment: yes i do use numpy

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506204/replace-sub-part-of-matrix-by-another-small-matrix-in-numpy

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605511/7207392)

Comment: @PaulPanzer
.. subclassing sounds problem related. How is it working out?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In your example you would use `mat_bigger[bs_[off_min:off_max]] = ...`

Comment: To construct the first expression from a couple of lists, you'll have to construct a tuple of slices.  You could package that as a function, or following the `np.s_` model as a class `__getitem__`.  That's just a user interface issue.  Functionality is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a tuple of `slice` objects. For example:

```
mat_big = np.zeros((4, 5, 6))
mat_small = np.random.rand(2, 2, 2)

off_min = [2, 3, 4]
off_max = [4, 5, 6]

slices = tuple(slice(start, end) for start, end in zip(off_min, off_max))

mat_big[slices] = mat_small
```