# Replacing 3D submatrix in Numpy and OpenCV2

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

[Replace sub part of matrix by another small matrix in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506204/replace-sub-part-of-matrix-by-another-small-matrix-in-numpy) generally seems to work for my purposes but I'm running into something I can't reconcile. Consider the following code, that creates two 3D matrices the shape of OpenCV2 webcam input, (in my case (480, 640, 3)), one of all 1s (`frame`) and one of random floats (`rgb_noise_mask`), replaces a specified submatrix in `frame` with the same submatrix of `rgb_noise_mask`, and displays it to the screen. This code works as intended, displaying a block of RGB-based static on a field of white.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

frame = np.ones(frame.shape)
rgb_noise_mask = np.random.random(size=frame.shape)

while True:
    boxes = [[300,300,30,30]]
    for box in boxes:
        x, y, width, height = box
        frame[y:y2, x:x2] = rgb_noise_mask[y:y2, x:x2]
        
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now take off the training wheels and use the actual webcam input instead of faking it. That same box now appears as uniform black instead of the expected colors:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

rgb_noise_mask = np.random.random(size=frame.shape)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    boxes = [[300,300,30,30]]
    for box in boxes:
        x, y, width, height = box
        frame[y:y2, x:x2] = rgb_noise_mask[y:y2, x:x2]
        
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
        
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Why is this, and how can I get around it? Further adding to my confusion is that if I replace `frame[y:y2, x:x2] = rgb_noise_mask[y:y2, x:x2]` with `frame[y:y2, x:x2] = frame[y:y2, x:x2][::-1]` in the second code sample it behaves as expected and displays the live output with that square mirrored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `ret, frame = cap.read()` returns `frame` as a numpy array  with `dtype=np.uint8`, while `rgb_noise_mask` is float between `0,1`, so all `0` when converted to `uint8`.

A simple fix is to generate noise as integers with `randint`:

```
rgb_noise_mask = np.random.randint(0,256, size=frame.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: Big d'oh moment given elsewhere I have lines like `frame = (rgb_mask * frame).astype(np.uint8)`. Thank you!